# What is a partial regulator?

Tags: ecology

[image: Img]

**Source**: [MY textbook-NCERT 12th Biology-Ch: Organisms and Population](http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lebo113.pdf)
(Pg 7 of pdf/Pg 223 of the book)

Is this graph for Partial regulators correct? Isn't it that animals tend to be regulators first and then when they can't maintain homeostasis anymore, they tend to conform aka adapt themselves to the surrounding for better survival?

So shouldn't the graph for Partial Regulators first be a **straight-line parallel to the axis** (signifying constant internal environment aka Homeostasis) upto **certain** *External surroundings level* and then be the **inclined straight line when it behaves as conformer ?**

I would like to know where I am wrong in my logic or Is it that The graph is wrong in my book ?

Comment: Why initial should be regulation? Upto a certain level? When the text says: Some species have evolved
the ability to regulate, but only over a **limited range** of environmental
conditions, beyond which they simply conform. Could it not be like confirming at both sides of limited range, ie conforming at low and high conditions.

Comment: I haven't really encountered this term before and it seems there are not many original sources of this term; I cannot find any scientific article that uses this term. So this term is apparently not a standard one. Also, as pointed out by @JM97, most organism can achieve homeostasis only in a limited range and it doesn't have to be limited at one specific end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the graph you indicated, might saying the following matter:

Let's take an example. " *Some snails and fish  go into aestivation  to avoid summer-related problems-heat and dessication."*  Now, when summer comes after the season Spring, the temperature gradually rises. The fishes can generally  withstand upto a threshold limit of temperature, and *conforms upto this threshold limit.* When their   comfortable weather breaks due to rising temperature, then they enter Aestivation and the graph now starts paralleling the X-axis.

Look, the graph *doesn't parallel to the " Conformers' line"* from the origin, but *deviates* with a little angle from that line : that implies *the organism was trying to regulate* against the external environment at first.

Undoubtedly, it's my own opinion, may carry some shortcomings generally.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Answers on this site are expected to be based on facts (not opinion or speculation) and consequently are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion, and therefore is inappropriate for this site. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] or delete your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: well your point of view is really different and original, though I am a little skeptical about it, it really relates to the paraphrase written in the same book on the next page relating to Partial regulator